# Set first day of week in JDateChooser

Tags: java, dayofweek, jdatechooser

I need some help to be able to set the first day of week from Sunday to Monday (change SMTWTFS to MTWTFSS) in `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser`, I tried like this with no result, I'm using version 1.3.3 of JDateChooser:

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
dateChooser.getCalendar().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Comment: I know it is an old question, but I am trying to find the answer to it. Did you find a way to do it other than changing to a different Locale ?

Answer (score 0):

Following the conventions of proper getter implementation, getCalendar() probably returns a *copy* of the calendar used. Therefore your call to setFirstDayOfWeek() is on an object that is *not* the calendar object of your JDateChooser.

I can't seem to find the documentation for JDateChooser 1.3.3, but if setCalendar() exists, this should work:

```
Calendar c = dateChooser.getCalendar();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
dateChooser.setCalendar(c);
```

Comment: `setFirstDayOfWeek` is void, it can't be applied to `setCalendar(Calendar c)`, you need to store `dateChooser.getCalendar()` into a `Calendar` object, then use `setFirstDayOfWeek` on that object, then pass it as parameter to the `setCalendar` method.

Comment: Ok, I do like this and it doesn't change the first day of week, is still Sunday.  JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
  dateChooser.setCalendar(calendar);

Comment: Ok, seems that the first day of the week is changed to Monday if we set a locale for a country for which the week first day is Monday.   Locale locale = new Locale("da", "DK");
  JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
  dateChooser.setLocale(locale);

Comment: Still I would like to find if possible a way to change only the first day of week.

Comment: @BackSlash You are correct, I've modified my answer to reflect your comments